# How send OUTPUT parameter to MySql stored procedure using FromSqlRaw() in c# entity framework core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

In Visual Studio Code C# Project I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.8 and MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.5.

I need to call Mysql stored procedure with output parameter using FromSqlRaw() and recive an MySqlException:
**"OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine ID_SP_Clientes_Validar is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger"**.

If I use ADO.NET can solve the problem, but i don't want use CommandText

### Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `ID_SP_Clientes_Validar`(IN `cliente` decimal(6,0), OUT `mensaje_alta` TINYTEXT)

BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM id_clientes WHERE clnumero = cliente;
    SET mensaje_alta = 'Cliente Valido.';
END
```

### C# Code:

```
var arParams = new[] {
new MySqlParameter("@cliente", MySqlDbType.Decimal)
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = clienteId
            },
            new MySqlParameter("@mensaje_alta", MySqlDbType.TinyText )
            {
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                Value = ""
            }
        };

var cliente = await context.miCliente.FromSqlRaw<ClienteGet>("CALL D_SP_Clientes_Validar(@cliente,@mensaje_alta)",arParams).ToListAsync();
```

Please help me!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe [this link](https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/08/03/ef-core-call-stored-procedures-out-parameters.html) might help.

Comment: Thanks @AliK for your message, but in the example you show me they use SQL (I need MySql). Anyway, I had already tried it but MySql does not support the word "OUTPUT" next to the parameter

Comment: In mysql tis OUT not OUTPUT so parameter would look like OUT total INT for example.

Comment: Should it be `"CALL D_SP_Clientes_Validar(@cliente,@mensaje_alta)"` with an `@` before `mensaje_alta`?

Comment: I made a mistake transcribing the code. In the code of the program I use @mensaje_alta.
Thanks

Comment: you say that it should be like this? 

var cliente = await context.miCliente.FromSqlRaw<ClienteGet>("CALL D_SP_Clientes_Validar(@cliente, OUT @mensaje_alta)",arParams).ToListAsync();

or

var cliente = await context.miCliente.FromSqlRaw<ClienteGet>("CALL D_SP_Clientes_Validar(@cliente, OUT @mensaje_alta TINYTEXT)",arParams).ToListAsync();

both throw the error SYNTAX ERROR

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by EF Core when using MySQL.

The underlying issue is that `FromSqlRaw` uses `CommandType.Text` but ADO.NET providers for MySQL have no ability to return an output parameter from text commands ([MySql.Data bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75267), [MySqlConnector bug](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/231)), fundamentally due to limitations in the MySQL protocol.

There is more discussion in these issues:

- [`FromSqlRaw()` and `ParameterDirection.Output` - efcore](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21433)
- [Parameter direction not supported in `CommandType.Text` - MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/231)